# Angular retrigger subscription to http call

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component, where I am fetching the data to be displayed via a service. I am subscribing to the service method (it’s just passing an HTTP response as observable) in the ngOnInit method of the component.

I now need to update the data, and trigger the call again. (toggleKpi method in the code below)

What is the best way to do this? I do not want to unsubscribe and resubscribe on every refresh.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { KpiService } from '../services/kpi.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Kpi } from '../models/kpi.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-kpi-list',
  templateUrl: './kpi-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./kpi-list.component.scss']
})
export class KpiListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  kpis: Kpi[] = [];
  deviceId: string;
  kpiSubscription: Subscription;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'info', 'version', 'description', 'unit', 'select'];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private kpiService: KpiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.deviceId = this.route.snapshot.parent.paramMap.get('deviceId');
    this.kpiSubscription = this.kpiService.getKpiConfiguration(this.deviceId).subscribe(res => {
      this.kpis = res.body;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.kpiSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  toggleKpi(element): void {
    // Here I need to refresh / retrigger the data
  }

}
```

Comment: `http` completes.  You don't need to unsubscribe manually (although that will prevent the subscriber from running if the user navigates away from the page before the http call completes).  And since it's completed, you can't "refresh" on the same subscription without making some changes to your `KipService#getKpiConfiguration` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `repeatWhen` operator:

```js
triggerer = new Subject<any>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.deviceId = this.route.snapshot.parent.paramMap.get('deviceId');
    this.kpiSubscription = this.kpiService.getKpiConfiguration(this.deviceId)
      .pipe(repeatWhen(this.triggerer))
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.kpis = res.body;
      });
  }

toggleKpi(element): void {
    // Here I need to refresh / retrigger the data
    this.triggerer.next();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just make a reusable method to fetch it.

```
export class KpiListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  kpis: Kpi[] = [];
  deviceId: string;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'info', 'version', 'description', 'unit', 'select'];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private kpiService: KpiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.deviceId = this.route.snapshot.parent.paramMap.get('deviceId');
    this.getKpi();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {

  }

   getKpi() {
      this.kpiService.getKpiConfiguration(this.deviceId).subscribe(res => {
      this.kpis = res.body;
    });
   }

  toggleKpi(element): void {
     this.getKpi();
  }

}
```